# iOS share comman view on diffrent view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7

I have implemented sliding menu code in iOS and want to share that single code for all view controller. is it possible ?? if yes then how can i implement this in my project ?
Can anyone help me for this ?

Here is a code I written in a view controller, and I want to share this code for all view controller.

```
(void)initslidingcode
{


    //selected button background

    _selectedbtnback=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Menu_selection.png"]];

    //end

    //sliding code

    slidestatus=0;
    _menu=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-190,60,190,450)];
    UIImageView *back=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Menu_Bg.png"]];
    back.frame=CGRectMake(0,-20,220,450);
    [_menu insertSubview:back atIndex:0];

    _menu.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
    [_leftmenu setTarget:self];
    [_leftmenu setAction:@selector(showmenu)];

    UIImageView *img=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45,7,80,80)];

    img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"profile.jpg"];
    img.layer.cornerRadius=img.frame.size.width/2;
    img.clipsToBounds=YES;
    img.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    img.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
    [_menu addSubview:img];


    UILabel *username=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,88,175,18)];
    username.text=@"Dilip Ingole";
    username.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    username.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [_menu addSubview:username];



     UIImageView *line=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,105,180,15)];
    line.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_divided_line.png"];
    [_menu addSubview:line];



    _activitybtn=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,110,180,37)];
    _inboxbtn=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,150,180,37)];
    _nutritionchartbtn=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,190,180,37)];
    _trainingplanbtn=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,230,180,37)];
    _heartbeatbtn=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,270,180,37)];
    _friends=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,310,180,37)];
    _goalsbtn=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,350,180,37)];
    _goshopbtn=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,390,180,37)];



    [_activitybtn setTitle:@"Activity" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    _activitybtn.contentHorizontalAlignment=UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
    [_activitybtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Menu_selection.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [_activitybtn addTarget:self action:@selector(openactivity) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    img=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 1, 40, 40)];
    img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Activity_icon.png"];
    _activitybtn.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 50, 0,0);
    [_activitybtn addSubview:img];
    [_menu addSubview:_activitybtn];

    UIImageView *line1=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,145,180,15)];
    line1.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_divided_line.png"];
    [_menu addSubview:line1];


    [_inboxbtn setTitle:@"Inbox" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_inboxbtn.titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
    [_inboxbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Menu_selection.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [_inboxbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(openinbox) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    img=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 1, 40, 40)];
    img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Msgbox_icon.png"];
    _inboxbtn.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,30);
    [_inboxbtn addSubview:img];
    [_menu addSubview:_inboxbtn];

    UIImageView *line2=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,183,180,15)];
    line2.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_divided_line.png"];
    [_menu addSubview:line2];



    [_nutritionchartbtn setTitle:@"Nutrition Chart" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_nutritionchartbtn.titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
    [_nutritionchartbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Menu_selection.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [_nutritionchartbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(opennutritionchart) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    img=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 1, 40, 40)];
    img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Nutrition_Icon.png"];
    _nutritionchartbtn.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,45, 0,0);
    [_nutritionchartbtn addSubview:img];
    [_menu addSubview:_nutritionchartbtn];

    UIImageView *line3=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,223,180,15)];
    line3.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_divided_line.png"];
    [_menu addSubview:line3];




    [_trainingplanbtn setTitle:@"Training Plan" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_trainingplanbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Menu_selection.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [_trainingplanbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(opentrainingplan) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    img=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 1, 40, 40)];
    img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Training_icon.png"];
    _trainingplanbtn.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 30, 0,0);
    [_trainingplanbtn addSubview:img];
    [_menu addSubview:_trainingplanbtn];

    UIImageView *line4=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,263,180,15)];
    line4.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_divided_line.png"];
    [_menu addSubview:line4];



    [_heartbeatbtn setTitle:@"Heart Beat" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_heartbeatbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Menu_selection.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [_heartbeatbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(openheartbeat) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    img=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 1, 40, 40)];
    img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"heart_icon.png"];
    _heartbeatbtn.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,20, 0,0);
    [_heartbeatbtn addSubview:img];
    [_menu addSubview:_heartbeatbtn];

    UIImageView *line5=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,303,180,15)];
    line5.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_divided_line.png"];
    [_menu addSubview:line5];



    [_friends setTitle:@"Friends" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_friends setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Menu_selection.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [_friends addTarget:self action:@selector(openfriends) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    img=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 1, 40, 40)];
    img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Friends_icon.png"];
    _friends.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0, 0,5);
    [_friends addSubview:img];
    [_menu addSubview:_friends];

    UIImageView *line6=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,343,180,15)];
    line6.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_divided_line.png"];
    [_menu addSubview:line6];



    [_goalsbtn setTitle:@"Goals" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_goalsbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Menu_selection.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [_goalsbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(opengoals) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    img=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 1, 40, 40)];
    img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Goals_icon.png"];
    _goalsbtn.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0,25);
    [_goalsbtn addSubview:img];
    [_menu addSubview:_goalsbtn];

    UIImageView *line7=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,383,180,15)];
    line7.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_divided_line.png"];
    [_menu addSubview:line7];



    [_goshopbtn setTitle:@"Go Shop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_goshopbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Menu_selection.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [_goshopbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(opengoshop) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    img=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 1, 40, 40)];
    img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Shoping Icon.png"];
    _goshopbtn.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0,0);
    [_goshopbtn addSubview:img];
    [_menu addSubview:_goshopbtn];


    //sliding


}
-(void)showmenu
{

    [_menu removeFromSuperview];
    _menu.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

    if (slidestatus==0)
    {

        slidestatus=1;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
            _menu.frame = CGRectMake(0,60,190,450);

        }];
    }
    else
    {
        slidestatus=0;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
            _menu.frame = CGRectMake(-190,60,190,450);
        }];
    }

    [self.view insertSubview:_menu atIndex:100];

}

-(void)openactivity
{

    //open activity controller

}

-(void)openinbox
{
    [_inboxbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Menu_selection.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        //open activity controller

}
-(void)opennutritionchart
{
    //open activity controller

}
-(void)opentrainingplan
{
    //open activity controller

}

-(void)openheartbeat
{
    //open activity controller

    NSLog(@"heart controller");

}
-(void)openfriends
{
    //open activity controller

}
-(void)opengoals
{
    //open activity controller

}
-(void)opengoshop
{
    //open activity controller

}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    slidestatus=0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
        _menu.frame = CGRectMake(-190,60,190,450);

    }];

}
```

Comment: Create slide menu as a singleton. That way you will have only one instance of view controller and you can add it to any view. This is one of the ways to do it.There might be other efficient ways as well.

Comment: ok i will try using that way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This guys did wonderful job with side menu.

There is also integrations instructions.

[MVYSideMenu](https://github.com/mobivery/MVYSideMenu)

Anyway, To achieve your task, consider to manage your side menu  from the `AppDelegate` and consider to add the side menu on top of the `appDelegate.window` same as `UITabBarController`, for example.